# Buffer overflow not working as expected

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am trying to execute a buffer overflow. I got it almost working as EIP points to the first instruction of my shellcode. However, when doing this in GDB it produces a SIGSEGV and I do not understand why.

Here is what the situation looks like when my program exits:

```
gdb$ run conf160

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------[regs]
  EAX: 0x90909090  EBX: 0x62413961  ECX: 0x00000000  EDX: 0xBFFFFAB0  o d I t S z a P c 
  ESI: 0x31624130  EDI: 0x41326241  EBP: 0x62413362  ESP: 0xBFFFFAE4  EIP: 0xBFFFFB21
  CS: 0073  DS: 007B  ES: 007B  FS: 0000  GS: 0033  SS: 007B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------[code]
=> 0xbffffb21:  xor    eax,eax
   0xbffffb23:  push   eax
   0xbffffb24:  push   0x68732f2f
   0xbffffb29:  push   0x6141622f
   0xbffffb2e:  xor    BYTE PTR [ecx+0x61],al
   0xbffffb31:  xor    DWORD PTR [ecx+0x61],eax
   0xbffffb34:  xor    al,BYTE PTR [ecx+0x61]
   0xbffffb37:  xor    ebp,ecx
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0xbffffb21 in ?? ()
```

Why doesn't the program executes the instruction at 0xbffffb21?

Thanks

Comment: The simple answer: You tried to access invalid memory and it stopped you from doing so. I guess gdb has a builtin memory check or something like that, or it is the kernel utilising the MPU (Memory Protection Unit) of your processor. If I recall it correctly, this happens if your invalid pointer is in another page boundary than your other valid code.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're shellcode is on the stack?

Answer (score 1):

> it produces a SIGSEGV and I do not understand why.

Most likely reason: your stack is not executable.

Most sufficiently recent Linux systems try to protect against executable code on the stack by linking programs with `-z noexecstack` linker options by default.

You can check whether your program is linked in this way by running:

```
readelf -Wl conf160 | grep GNU_STACK
```

A typical output would look like this (it's the `RW` at the end that is important):

```
GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW    8
```

See also this [document](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/GNU_stack_quickstart).